# Army Intelligence Posting

Tags: world-war-2, india

Can anyone tell me what the acronym F.I.C.S stands for in relation to a French speaking stenographer being posted to India in April 1945?
The acronym appears on the service record from TNA of a secretary in the Intelligence Service in 1945. FICS appears as the posting in 29.4.45. She appears in Calcutta in another document then in August 1945 is sent to Malaya. I thought the I C might be Intelligence Corps but then S for Service wouldn't make sense!

Comment: Hi, Denise -- welcome to G&FH.SE!  Can you tell us where you found the document on which this acronym appears?  Please don't post the name of the individual concerned if that person was born less than 100 years ago -- what I'm asking for is the type or name of the the document itself and/or the agency that issued it, to get a better sense of the historical context.

Comment: Likewise welcome to G&FH SE!  When you edit your question can you perhaps also tell us which country posted this stenographer to India, please?  Knowing whether it was the US, Britain, Canada or another country could make quite a difference for where to begin searching.  I'm guessing it starts Foreign Intelligence and probably ends in Service but what the C stands for is harder.

Comment: The reference to TNA suggests the sending country was the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect this might be a reference to the French IndoChina Section of the SOE, as referenced here: [Silent Partners: SOE's French Indo-China Section, 1943–1945 (abstract)](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=61191) and here: [“Indochina” (1944-1954)](http://www.defense.gouv.fr/english/layout/set/print/dgse/tout-le-site/indochina)